# Best and unique primary key for streaming data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Newbie question....  In a project, capturing streaming market data onto an SQL server using JDBC, I am retrieving the data using Java from the broker's systems,...  What's best and unique primary key possible to use on the SQL database .. and what's its java equivalent.  The project is to capture forex market data continuously for the 6 trading days straight (144 hours).  - Thank you.

## This is my code.  It works. No doubt you pros can efficiencize it but here's the relevant class.  I am inserting the UniqueIdentifier as a varchar(MAX) onto the sql database. Thanks.

```
package packagename;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;


public class QuoteInserter extends DownloaderMarketData {
    private static final String jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static final String jdbcURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;user=sa;password=974974;";


    static void quoteInsert(double bid0, double ask0, String time1) {



                System.out.println("Program started");
                try
                {  Class.forName(jdbcDriver).newInstance();
                    System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded");  }
                catch (Exception err)
                {  System.err.println("Error loading JDBC driver");
                    err.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    System.exit(0);    }

                Connection databaseConnection= null;

                try
                {
                    //Connect to the database
                    databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL);
                    System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                }
                catch (SQLException err)
                {
                    System.err.println("Error connecting to the database");
                    err.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    System.exit(0);
                }


        Date date = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat4 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat5 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat6 = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat7 = new SimpleDateFormat("SSSSSSSSS");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat8 = new SimpleDateFormat("a");


        String year     =dateFormat1.format(date);
        String month    =dateFormat2.format(date);     
        String day      =dateFormat3.format(date);
        String hour     =dateFormat4.format(date);
        String minute   =dateFormat5.format(date);
        String second   =dateFormat6.format(date);
        String microsec =dateFormat7.format(date);
        String ampm     =dateFormat8.format(date);
        String bidFromDouble = Double.toString(bid0);
        String askFromDouble = Double.toString(ask0);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(500000000);
        String randomNumber = Integer.toString(n) ;        

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(year);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(month);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(day);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(hour);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(minute);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(second);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(microsec);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(ampm);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(bidFromDouble);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(askFromDouble);
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(randomNumber);



                try
                { Statement sqlStatement = databaseConnection.createStatement();
                    String commandString="INSERT INTO [dbo].[BidAsk02] (UniqueIdentifier,Hour,Bid1,Ask1) VALUES ('"+sb+"','"+hour+"','"+bid0+"','"+ask0+"')";  

                    //print the command string to the screen
                    System.out.println("\nCommand string:");
                    System.out.println(commandString);

                    //execute the command using the execute method
                    sqlStatement.execute(commandString);
                    System.out.println("Closing database connection");
                    //close the database connection


                    databaseConnection.close();     }

                catch (SQLException err)
                {  System.err.println("SQL Error");
                    err.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    System.exit(0);   }

                System.out.println("Program finished");


}
}
```

Comment: When you ask "Whats the best way to do X" there is no single correct answer because its more of a debatable topic. I think your question is a bit too open-ended.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for high-level design discussions, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: iHazCode:  Thank you sir, being a newbie and a non-programmer, trying to stay away from T-SQL just work with regular SQL.      jarlh: I am using MS SQL server.     shellter:  I'll post my code, please bear with me.  thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

In high throughput (banking) systems and SCADA implementations, I've seen T-SQL's UniqueIdentifier data-type be stacked. Basically you would have a two or more columns with this data-type which is basically a GUID.

The downside is on the application side you are likely treating these basically as a string and then leveraging grep for better performance if you have to do 'in process' actions on a collection of them.

Note: The stacking thing is a very paranoid approach. While concatenating two GUIDs will GREATLY decrease the possibility of having duplicate identifiers. It's already extremely improbable that you would run into a duplicate using even a single GUID field for your high throughput system as the algo used to generate the GUID is usually based on a number of techniques including Current Time, RNG, Hardware Identifiers, and other factors to emulate uniqueness.

Comment: Hello All... Correction.  Although UniqueIdentifier, it's not explicitly labelled as a primary key. Why can't varchar(MAX) serve primary key. ..using Microsoft SQL server management studio. Has anyone experienced this?.. So anyways I changed it to varchar(50) and now it took the primary key option. And I did reduce the UniqueIdentifier by taking out the -'s so can fit the 50 character max.  Thanks

Comment: That should be sufficient. You may want to investigate a little more any implications related to read speed as this scales however. Indexing was never going to be super helpful if your using multiple GUIDs. Specifically trying to perform lookups on large sets via string columns is taxing on the engine.